# How can I include escaped characters in a jquery-ui dialog button?

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I am trying to put the '¡' character (`&iexcl;` in HTML) in one of my jQuery UI dialog buttons, but I can't figure out how this works. Here's my code:

```
registerhtml.dialog({
            modal: true,
            title: 'Registro en entreSartenes',
            resizable: false,
            buttons: [
                {
                    text: "&iexcl;Reg&iacute;strate!",
                    click: function(){
                        $(this).dialog('close');
                        connect();
                    }
                },
                {
                    text: "No gracias",
                    click: function() {
                        $(this).dialog('close');
                    }
                }
            ]
        });
```

When the dialog pops up, I actually get `"&iexcl;Reg&iacute;strate!"` in my button. I have also tried putting the unescaped text directly in the JS code ("¡Regístrate!") but I get weird characters when it gets displayed.

Does anyone know a solution for this?

Comment: You'll be able to put the actual character in your code if you use the right encoding. Is your javascript embeded in html or is it a javascript file? What encoding is specified in the HTTP headers or HTML meta elements?

Comment: ah, yes, that was it. my file was ANSI encoded and changing it to UTF-8 fixed the problem. if you want to submit an answer I'll be happy to mark it as the right one. Thanks!!

Comment: Great, I thought we'd need more info but it looks like you figured out the rest of it.

Comment: Look here: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13718836/jquery-ui-encoding-nightmare][1] for the solution.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13718836/jquery-ui-encoding-nightmare

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you're using javascript and not HTML, you'll need to put the actual character, not the HTML entity. You'll be able to do it if you use the right encoding (like UTF-8, but any encoding that can represent the characters you need should work). Make sure your file is UTF-8 and that it is interpreted as such by the browser, by setting the encoding in the HTTP headers or the HTML meta elements.

Comment: But, what will happen with strings that actually need to be encoded?, what should I do if I want to put this inside a button: Add L'amie to "friends"

Comment: @Adrian Salazar If you put it directly inside an HTML attribute, you'll have to use an HTML entity for the quotes, but if it's directly in javascript code, just insert a backslash before the quote to escape it.

Answer (score 1):

There is always an alternative in jQuery, you can do this:

```
var text = $('<i/>').html('&iacute;').text();
alert(text); // ---> á
```

It will create an unattached `i` tag, then evaluate the string `&iacute;` as HTML, then retrieve the *rendered* text content.

Answer (score 0):

Also i found out you can use

\hexcode

works well

```
"Har hentet V\xE6rge": function() {
      $( this ).dialog( "close" );
```

http://www.javascripter.net/faq/accentedcharacters.htm